# How do you write a C program to state the input and output of a string?

Tags: c

I have written a C program to accept the input of a string and then print it. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    char name[20];
    printf("Enter your name: ");
    scanf("%s",name);
    printf("Your name is %s.",name);
    return 0;
}
```

Is this the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens when you run it? Does it give you the correct output?

Basically, yes, it is the right answer. However there are some problems:

- Only names of up to 19 characters long can be accepted (1 character is required for null termination of the string). More than that and you have a [buffer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow) vulnerability, which is a serious security risk. You can fix that by limiting the amount of data that can be read to that of the receiving buffer.
- `"%s"` consumes leading whitespace characters and input is terminated on the first whitespace character. You might not want
  that to happen if white space is significant.
- A new line is not printed after the string is displayed.

Answer (score -1):

It is quite perfect man.
Only a few aspects...
If your name's length is bigger than the max lenght of your char, it will crash.
It also would look prettier with:

```
printf("\nYour name is....."); //use \n starting your new line. It will look clearer
```

But the important thing is that: IT WORKS!!!